# Matlab : Dimension reduction

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

LEt  `x_t = F(x_{t-1})`  be a discret in time one dynamical system in [chaotic regime.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory)

Starting from an initial condition  `x_0`, we can generate a time series = `x_t` where  `t =1,2,...,T`  indicates the time index.
 `s_t = 1`  if `x_t` `> c`  otherwise  `s_t = 0` 
where  `c`  is the mean 
of the one-dimensional map. So each iterate of the map  `F`  gives a new symbol. Putting the sequences of 0's and 1's into a vector of symbols, we get  `{s} = s_0s_1s_2....`

Now, suppose we have a  3 dimensional system, let `d=3`. Let the first co-ordinate  be called `x`, the second coordinate y and the third as z yielding `(x,y,z)` that forms the  multidimensional system. My problem is how do I obain the symbolic dynamics for this case?

Example :

```
          x = 0.1, 0.45, 0.6,....,
          y = 0,   0.1, 0.45, 0.6,.....
          z = 0,    0,   0.1, 0.45,...
```

Will there be a symbolic sequence for each dimension or will a symbol be assigned to a point  (x,y,z) ? An explanation will be very helpful to clear the concept and then program.  Solution using any other existing technique on assigning symbols will also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In communications, you get one symbol for each point.

In your case you have 2 `1 bit` symbols, in one dimension, each symbol has a coordinate.

But nothing stops you from having 2 bit symbols in one dimension, like:

```
X=[ -c -c/3 c/3 c ]
```

You draw the decision frontiers by selecting the closest coordinate.

```
[ x<-2c/3, -2c/3<x<0, 0<x<2c/3, 2c/3<x]
```

Same principle applies to a multidimensional problem, ie for two dimensions and two bit symbols, you could distribute them like:

```
   (-c -c ) == 00
   (-c  c ) == 01
   ( c -c ) == 10
   ( c  c ) == 11
```

Note that you **need** at least `2 bit` symbols to make sense of this, otherwise you could project it to one dimension.

Now comes the tricky part: *Only if you don't have correlation between your dimensions, you can exploit independence on your frontiers*

Correlation introduced by the channel (or the noise), means that the decision frontier

```
[ x<0 y<0, x<0 y>0, x>0 y<0, x>0 y>0 ]
```

won't be optimal.

On the other hand, if you can assume dimensional independence, It's easy to see that a good symbol assignment (like the one I made), allows to easily implement what you call `a symbolic sequence for each dimension`

```
{s}={ s_0, s_1, ... }
{s}={ deco(X_0), deco(Y_0), deco(X_1), deco(Y_1) ... }
```

with

```
deco(x){ return( x > 0) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has taken me some time to understand it but I am finding few parts difficult to follow. Would you please explain and correct me if wrong?Really appreciate your time and effort. (A) You have showed with 2 coordinates ( 2 dimensiona) I think. What I wanted to achieve is get one symbol for each point : when $(x = 0.1, y = 0.0, z = 0.0)$ is it possible to represent this point with either 0 or 1?

Comment: With a 3d coord you'll have at least 8 `3bit` symbols. Otherwise, you should be able to reduce the dimension

Comment: Is it possible to represent a point by only one symbol? It is not clear from your example. You say that a 3d coordinate will be represented by 3 bit symbol. But, this des not reduce the dimension. If a 3d coordinate is represented by one symbol then probably the dimension has been reduced to 1. My question is whether dimension can be reduced using few symbols for a multidimensional system?

Comment: You're mixing stuff, Symbols and dimensions are orthogonal concepts. Symbols are used to codify your message. Then you have a transmission channel with N dimensions, ie RF channels ( that can hold up to 2 dimensions per channel). You can map any amount of symbols to any amount of dimensions (as shown in my 4 symbols 1 dimension example). But doing that, means an increased cost in power (symbols are further from the 0), or lowering the noise tolerance (reducing inter symbol separation), or using more bandwidth (adding dimensions).